# Why might a plugin's 'do_shortcode' not work in an AJAX request?

Tags: ajax, plugin-contact-form-7, shortcode

**tl;dr:** Contact Form 7's shortcode doesn't work in an AJAX request when called with `do_shortcode`

*functions.php*

```
add_action('wp_ajax_ps_get_survey_form', 'ps_get_survey_form');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_ps_get_survey_form', 'ps_get_survey_form');

function ps_get_survey_form() {
    echo do_shortcode( '[contact-form-7 id="397" title="Contact form 1"]' );
    die();
}
```

*script.js*

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    $('#survey-modal').fancybox({
        href: ajaxurl,
        ajax: {
            type : "POST",
            data : {action: 'ps_get_survey_form'}
        }
    });
});
```

However,

```
echo do_shortcode( '[contact-form-7 id="397" title="Contact form 1"]' )
```

returns the shortcode string itself. It works fine if I put it in a template.

Try as I might (ludicrous things like wrapping it in a post/applying the_content filter, manually firing various actions that CF7 hooks into, etc) it refuses to translate itself into a form.

How do I debug this?

**EDIT**

@Kaiser sensibly suggests that I don't have access to do_shortcode. I tried to check this, with the following result:

```
function ps_get_survey_form() {

    //include( ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/shortcodes.php' ); 
    //Causes fatal error: cannot redeclare add_shortcode

    if ( function_exists( 'do_shortcode ' ) )  {
        echo "do_shortcode exists";
    } else {
        echo "do_shortcode doesn't exist";  // this gets echoed
    }

    do_shortcode( 'foo' );      // this fails silently, even though the function apparently hasn't been defined
    //foo();                    // Causes fatal error as expected

    //echo do_shortcode( '[contact-form-7 id="397" title="contact form 1"]' );
    die();
}
```

Comment: Maybe because the shortcode function hasn't been registered yet at that point?

Comment: @OneTrickPony - I agree that seems likely. The question is, how can I cause it to be registered (if you see what I mean)?

Comment: Just handle the ajax request yourself in the "wp" or "init" action. WP's admin-ajax was designed to be used in the administration area anyway

Comment: @OneTrickPony, thanks. that works. will post working code above for posterity.

Comment: Last time I looked through Contact Form 7, they didn't use the build in shortcode API, opting to role their own instead.  Worth checking out.

Comment: I don't know what is happening in ajax call. Because if i try `funtion_exists` as above for `get_option()` like this `if(function_exists('get_option')){echo 'exist';}else{echo 'not exist';}` it echo `not exist` but when i simply echo for example blog name `get_option('blogname');` it is printing the blog name. I can see it in the ajax response. If function not exist then how can it work. `do_shortcode()` also works when i try to get site title. but when i try to get post title it is not printing. What might be the problem. @onetrickpony

Comment: @sun Please read [ask] and ask your own question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is to sidestep admin-ajax restrictions by handling it yourself, as @OneTrickPony suggests.

```
add_action( 'init', function() { 
  ps_register_shortcode_ajax( 'ps_get_survey_form', 'ps_get_survey_form' ); 
} );

function ps_register_shortcode_ajax( $callable, $action ) {

  if ( empty( $_POST['action'] ) || $_POST['action'] != $action )
    return;

  call_user_func( $callable );
}

function ps_get_survey_form() {
    echo do_shortcode( '[contact-form-7 id="397" title="contact form 1"]' );
    die(); 
}
```

Answer (score 7):

WP Ajax runs both public as well as closed calls via `admin.php`. This means that you don't have access to the whole wp environment, such as `do_shortcode()`, which is inside `/wp-includes/shortcodes.php`.

This still can get worked around (and as well for oEmbed). See the following example that you could use in your AJAX callback to enable both *oEmbed* handlers as well as shortcode handlers for a `\WP_Post::post_content` property.

```
/** \WP_Post $post */
$post = get_post();

/** @var \WP_Embed $wp_embed */
global $wp_embed;

$wp_embed->post_ID = $post->ID;

// [embed] shortcode
$wp_embed->run_shortcode( $post->post_content );

// plain links on their own line
$wp_embed->autoembed( $post->post_content );

// Enable shortcodes
do_shortcode( $post->post_content );
```

---

**PROTip:** Never call `echo do_shortcode( '[some-short-code arg="foo"]' );` directly. A shortcode is just a *placeholder for the editor*. **Every** shortcode *must* have a callback attached. Use the callback instead. This saves you from running expensive Regex checks.

Comment: @djb Please add your solution not to the question, but as a new answer and mark it then as solution. Thanks.

Comment: will do. can you shed any light on the `function_exists` mystery?