# How do you use do_shortcode via AJAX call?

Tags: ajax, shortcode

I'm attempting to call a Contact Form 7 form using AJAX in a Wordpress theme.  I'd ideally like to use the Contact Form 7 shortcode to do this, however it doesn't seem as though do_shortcode is an available function when called using AJAX (it was just echoing out the shortcode itself).

I stumbled upon this question: 
[Why might a plugin's 'do_shortcode' not work in an AJAX request?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/53309/why-might-a-plugins-do-shortcode-not-work-in-an-ajax-request/53491#53491)

which was exactly my problem!  However the solution provided didn't work for me, and I'm pretty sure I implemented it the same way the original post did:

```
add_action( 'init', create_function('',  'register_shortcode_ajax( "cl_contact_us", "cl_contact_us" ); '));

function register_shortcode_ajax( $callable, $action ) {
    if ( empty( $_POST['action'] ) || $_POST['action'] != $action )
        return;
    call_user_func( $callable );
}

function cl_contact_us() {
    echo do_shortcode( '[contact-form-7 id="7" title="Contact form 1"]' );
    die(); 
}
```

The only thing I had to change was how the anonymous function was being called from the add_action function (for some reason using a traditional anonymous function wasn't working, but using the PHP function works fine).

Aside from the above, the only thing that's radically different is the jQuery AJAX call, but I believe it's basically the same...

```
var ajaxurl = '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>';
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a#contact-button').click(event, function() {
            event.preventDefault();
            $.post(
               ajaxurl, 
                {
                    'action':'cl_contact_us',
                }, 
            function(response) {
                $('#form').append(response);
            });
        });
    });
```

This is successfully performing an AJAX call, but it's still just echoing out the shortcode, not the form.

I hope this is enough info, if you need any more I'll be here all day :)
Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why might a plugin's 'do_shortcode' not work in an AJAX request?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/53309/why-might-a-plugins-do-shortcode-not-work-in-an-ajax-request)

Comment: _possible_ duplicate...

Comment: Yes, I used that question as a reference, but it didn't end up working for me, and I couldn't leave any additional comments on the question.  I thought opening a new question was my best option.  Apologies if this is a dupe though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think it is possible to do this by using the contact form 7 plugin. Because the plugin uses `bind('click')` on the submit button JS trigger, where it supposed to be `live('click')` to work on an AJAX loaded form.

As an alternative you can use a custom made contact form, or hide the contact form by default using JS and show it on a click of a button. The second solution is easier and still works without JS.

Hope this help