# Shortcode in AJAX popup

Tags: plugins, shortcode, ajax, facebook

I am trying to use a shortcode from Ultimate Facebook plugin to display a FB connect button in an AJAX popup and can't seem to get it work properly.
I searched and used the solution given by djb in this question - [Why might a plugin's 'do_shortcode' not work in an AJAX request?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/53309/why-might-a-plugins-do-shortcode-not-work-in-an-ajax-request), but it worked only partially. Ideally, I want a user to be able to sign in using FB and then save the list to her account. I want to use the plugin instead of embedding direct code because creates a new user in wordpress too when someone uses FB connect.

Procedure to reproduce issue -

- Go to http://www.ajaymreddy.com/stg/country/india/#
- Click on Start
- Select any of checboxes - take care to not click on the text against
  the checkboxes
- Click on Save button in the popup 
  If you are not logged in, the fb connect button should show up. However, only the shortcode text is currently showing up.

**Code in functions.php** -

```
//From https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/53309/why-might-a-plugins-do-shortcode-not-work-in-an-ajax-request
add_action( 'init', function() {
  ps_register_shortcode_ajax( 'show_fblogin', 'show_fblogin' );
} );

function ps_register_shortcode_ajax( $callable, $action ) {
  if ( empty( $_POST['action'] ) || $_POST['action'] != $action )
    return;
  call_user_func( $callable );
}

function show_fblogin(){
        if (!is_user_logged_in())
          echo do_shortcode('[wdfb_connect]');
        die ();
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_show_fblogin', 'show_fblogin' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_show_fblogin', 'show_fblogin' );
```

**Code in ajax file** -

```
$(document).on( 'click', '#saveBtn', function (){
            if (myAjax.loggedin==1)
            {
                    jQuery.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: myAjax.ajaxurl,

                    data: {
                            action: 'save_whslist',
                            selected: selected.toString(),
                            whsNonce: myAjax.selectNonce,
                    },
                    success: function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest){
                            selected = [];
                            modal.close();
                            $("input.whsites").prop('disabled', true);
                            $("input.whsites").prop('checked', false);
                    },
                    error: function(MLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
                            alert(errorThrown+' fail');
                    }
                    });
            }
            else
            {
                    jQuery.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: myAjax.ajaxurl,

                    data: {
                            action: 'show_fblogin',
                            selected: selected.toString(),
                            whsNonce: myAjax.selectNonce,
                    },
                    success: function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest){
                            modal.open({content: "<p>Please login to save your travel list<br /><span>No auto posts on your wall!</span></p>"+data});
                    },
                    error: function(MLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
                            alert(errorThrown+' fail');
                    }
                    });
            }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding the solution for posterity -
I solved it by adding FB.XFBML.parse(); once the AJAX call returned succesfully. Hope this helps.