# How to use shortcodes on a widget sidebar when doing an ajax call?

Tags: shortcode, ajax, widget-text

I'm trying to use a shortcode from [Promotion Slider Plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/promotion-slider/) inside a widget when doing an ajax call. As said [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/53309/why-might-a-plugins-do-shortcode-not-work-in-an-ajax-request/53491#53491), I could achieve it doing:

```
add_action( 'init', function() { 
  ps_register_shortcode_ajax( 'ps_get_slider', '8' ); 
} );

function ps_register_shortcode_ajax( $callable, $action ) {
if(isset($_POST['href'])) {
      $pageId = preg_match( '/^http:\/\/.+\/\?page_id=\d+$/', $_POST['href'] ) ? substr( strrchr( $_POST['href'], '=' ), 1 ) : '8' ;

      if ( empty( $pageId ) || $pageId != $action )
        return;

      call_user_func( $callable );
}
}

function ps_get_slider() {
    //require_once('../wp-load.php'); Nothing changes
    if ( dynamic_sidebar('Slider') ) : else : endif;
    //echo do_shortcode( '[promoslider post_type="news" height="300px" width="70%" numberposts="5" start_on="first" display_title="fancy" display_excerpt="excerpt"  pause_on_hover="pause"]' );  Same output than above
    die(); 
}
```

but I'm just getting the literal output: `[promoslider post_type="news" height="300px" width="70%" numberposts="5" start_on="first" display_title="fancy" display_excerpt="excerpt"  pause_on_hover="pause"]`.

Any idea of how could achieve it?

*As a note, I first tried just adding `if ( dynamic_sidebar('Slider') ) : else : endif;` into the ajax template, but didn't work.*

Comment: You may need the `widget_text` filter to resolve shortcodes in widgets as this doesn't happen by default, see http://digwp.com/2010/03/shortcodes-in-widgets/ for a reference.

Comment: @MarioPeshev - The shortcode works right if it's not an Ajax call. I had tried your suggestion adding this filter at the start of `ps_get_slider()` function without success (same output).