# How to load a plugin when doing an Ajax call?

Tags: plugins, shortcode, ajax

I have posted this question: [How to use shortcodes on a widget sidebar when doing an ajax call?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/128971/how-to-use-shortcodes-on-a-widget-sidebar-when-doing-an-ajax-call), with no answers. Now I want to ask a more specific question.

The problem seems to be that the shortcode is not processed by the plugin., as if I replace the shortcode with e.g. `[audio src="audioFile.ogg"]` it works perfect.

So I'm guessing that I could make it work if the plugin is loaded before. But I don't know how to achieve it (maybe I'm wrong with it).

Any suggestion?

This is the code in `functions.php`:

```
add_action( 'init', function() { 
  ps_register_shortcode_ajax( 'ps_get_slider', '8' ); 
} );

function ps_register_shortcode_ajax( $callable, $action ) {
    if(isset($_POST['href'])) {
        $pageId = preg_match( '/^http:\/\/.+\/\?page_id=\d+$/', $_POST['href'] ) ? substr( strrchr( $_POST['href'], '=' ), 1 ) : '8' ;

        if ( empty( $pageId ) || $pageId != $action )
            return;

        call_user_func( $callable );
    }
}

function ps_get_slider() {
    //require_once('../wp-load.php'); Nothing changes

    apply_filters('ps_register_shortcode_ajax', 'slider_widget_init');
    if ( dynamic_sidebar('Slider') ) : else : endif;
    //echo do_shortcode( '[promoslider post_type="news" height="300px" width="70%" numberposts="5" start_on="first" display_title="fancy" display_excerpt="excerpt"  pause_on_hover="pause"]' );
    get_template_part( 'home', 'ajax' );
    die(); 
}
```

The Slider side-bar is loaded just in home and-home-ajax pages (id=8). It works right in home page, but not in home-ajax page.

Comment: Post your code please.

Comment: @s_ha_dum - Done

Comment: There is too much going on there for me to be be able to replicate the problem in any reasonable time. Please reduce that to a bare minimum sample case that demonstrates the problem. Sorry, but I need to paste that into a dev-stack and run the code. I don't have time to reverse engineer it. Also, this ___is___ the same question as your other one even if worded slightly differently. I'd delete one or the other.

Comment: @s_ha_dum - All right. Now it is the most relevant code.

Comment: @s_ha_dum - I'd prefer to delete one question when the problem is resolved.

Comment: The rules of the stack network are that you do not duplicate questions _at all_. Whether there are answers is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using ajax right.  Why are you adding your ajax callback function to the init action? You need to read http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Attach your ajax callback function to `wp_ajax_your_defined_action` like this:

`add_action( 'wp_ajax_your_defined_action', 'your_callbck_function' );`

For this to work you have to use wp-admin/admin-ajax.php as your ajax url and you have to post your_defined_action to action.

```
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: ajaxurl, //This is defined only on admin side
                data: {
                    action: 'your_defined_action',
                    some_var: 'Some Var Content'
                },
                success: function (response) {
                    alert(response);
                }
            });
```

Comment: Yes, I deleted this part of the code because I think it is right. You can check at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/128971/how-to-use-shortcodes-on-a-widget-sidebar-when-doing-an-ajax-call