# Why 'do_shortcode' doesn't work in a REST request?

Tags: shortcode, rest-api

Why `do_shortcode` doesn't work in a REST call ?

In the example below, `do_shortcode` exists, but the shortcode isn't interpreted.

### Route declaration

```
/*
       Adding a route with callback is interpret_shortcode function
*/
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function ()
{
       register_rest_route(
              'test',
              '/someContent',
              array(
                 'methods' => 'GET',
                 'callback' => 'interpret_shortcode'
              )
       );
} );
```

### Shortcode call

```
function interpret_shortcode( $data )
{
   $content;

   if ( function_exists( 'do_shortcode' ) )  
   {
           $content = do_shortcode("[et_pb_text] abc [/et_pb_text]");
   } 
   else {
          $content = "do_shortcode is missing";
   }

   return array('content'=>$content); //Output "[et_pb_text] abc [/et_pb_text]"
}
```

In a REST call, are we in the same situation as the one describe [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/53309/why-might-a-plugins-do-shortcode-not-work-in-an-ajax-request) about Ajax request ?

Comment: You have an extra space in the `do_shortcode` inside the `function_exists`. Is that a typo in your question or is it your actual code?

Comment: OMG - so easy to fix  !

Comment: So i edit the question a bit because i'm stuck in the next step

Comment: Please clarify your problem. Does is it work now or is the problem still there?

Comment: @RRikesh help, but the probleme still there, `do_shortcode` doesn't do shortcode.

Comment: Well, I have tested and `do_shortcode` works normally in REST responses. Look like your shortcode isn't added correctly. Let me know how you added the shorcode.

Comment: @Dan you are right ! I am doing some test on my own, and in fact with an other short code (like contact form) that work great.

Comment: These short code come from Divi Builder. I suppose these shortcode works in a different way than traditional shortcode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution

I find a workaround for this issue. I post it for posterity.

This is an issue, several issue, between divi and REST Api.

In the exemple bellow, `register_rest_field` is used instead of `register_rest_route`, but the fix is valid for both method.

This solution could not be very futureproof. But, at least, their is no modification inside Divi Builder or Rest API.

```
/*
     Edit Rest call
*/
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function ()
{
   register_rest_field(
          'page',
          'content',
          array(
                 'get_callback'    => 'duo_get_divi_content',
                 'update_callback' => null,
                 'schema'          => null,
          )
       );
});

function duo_get_divi_content( $object, $field_name, $request )
{
   //Set is_singular to true to ovoid "read more issue"
   //Issue come from is_singular () in divi-builder.php line 73
   global $wp_query;
   $wp_query->is_singular = true;


   //Set divi shortcode
   //The 2 function bellow are define in 'init' but they are call in 'wp'
   //REST Api exit after 'parse_request' hook, it's before 'wp' so divi's shortcode are not set
   et_builder_init_global_settings ();
   et_builder_add_main_elements ();


   //Define $post, if not defined, divi will not add outter_content and inner_content warper
   //Issue come from get_the_ID() in divi-builder.php line 69
   global $post;
   $post = get_post ($object['id']);

   //Apply the_content's filter, one of them interpret shortcodes
   $output =  apply_filters( 'the_content', $post->post_content );

   return $output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Availability of shortcodes defined by plugins at any point of the code is undefined expect for (and even that is a maybe) singular content.

In most cases outside of that context you better call the function implementing it with the applicable parameters instead of "parsing" the shortcode.

Comment: Yep, In most cases, call the function directly is probably the best solution.   But in some situation, the content could contain several and different shortcode used by users.  For exemple if  `do_shortcode`  is call to parse a post content build with a builder.

Comment: Who said builder are immune to the same problems? ;)